# How to update the columnDef of an angular ui-grid column dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

So the issue I'm facing is I would like to update the `field` property of a `columnDef` definition to show a different value based on some configuration that's being passed into the directive.  I have a dumbed down version in this plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/gmjUcQsnIOpqWwkoYiI8?p=preview

Clicking the button in that plunk should switch the emails from `actual` to `pretend`.  It's looping over the `columnDefs` on scope and then altering the field to be `email.pretend` from `email.actual`.  Do I need some kind of "refresh" function after changing the columnDefs?  I tried `gridApi.core.refresh()` but that did not do anything.  Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 2):

http://plnkr.co/edit/ujIpJFFGRAwNUKiy0Bnm?p=preview

```
$scope.otherColumn = {displayName: 'Pretend', field: 'email.pretend'};
//change the field - is this possible???
$scope.changeField = function changeField() {
    $scope.otherColumn = $scope.columnDefs.splice(1, 1, $scope.otherColumn)[0];
}
```

You just add / remove the item from the `columnDefs` array and it will do it.

Answer (score 0):

So I thought I could update my grid similar to this but by reassigning an array to the columnsDef like this

```
var a = true;
//change the field - is this possible???
$scope.changeField = function changeField() {
  if (a) {
    $scope.columnDefs = [{ field: 'name' }, {
      displayName: 'Pretend',
      field: 'email.pretend'
    }];
  } else {
    $scope.columnDefs = [{ field: 'name' }, {
      displayName: 'Email',
      field: 'email.actual'
    }];
  }
  a = !a;
};
```

If you put that in the plnkr you'll see it doesn't have any effect.

That's because the assignment doesn't change the $scope.gridApi.
As @dave's answer suggests you need to modify the original columnsDef object from the initialization or the columns under the api won't be affected. I'm glad the code doesn't clone the object for the api or I'd have to dig into the api to make this change.